# How is potential difference created in an inductor

Tags: voltage, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

As far as I know potential difference can only be created by electric field created by static charges, but in case of inductor non-conservative electric field is induced.

Comment: You question is one which has been debated many times.  I think that the lecture by Ramamurti Shankar of Yale University is a good start to the understanding of this topic.  [Mutual & Self Inductance](https://oyc.yale.edu/physics/phys-201/lecture-11) starting at **37:47**. If you search this site using the words [potential difference inductor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=inductor+potential+difference) you will find a number of answers to your question.